# VS2015 Xamarin Parsing error while installing apk

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have created a sample android app using visual studio 2015 xamarin.
It's an empty app and when trying to install it's saying parse error while installing package. i have seen so many fixes for this problem but

please see my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<application android:label="mt01_app.Android"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: How are you creating the apk package?

Comment: by right clicking the solution and clicking archive

Comment: what kind of distribution method did you choose?

Comment: I just hv opened the folder and copied the apk file to my android phone

Comment: so you picked ad-hoc distribution?! Did you try installing the app through adb, the output might help as well.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, have you tried to recreate a new project?

Comment: that worked.thanks a lot malte